# In Ejb Session bean can we extend another session bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

Program:

> ```
> @Local
> interface AInter{
> //...
> }
> class A implements AInter{
> //...
> }
> @Local
> interface BInter extends AInter{
> //...
> }
> class B implements BInter {
> //...
> }
> In Backing:
> @Inject
> BInter binter; //It's work fine
> But If i tried 
> @Inject
> AInter aInter; //But if i try to access A interface from my backing.
> ```

It showed warning like this

`Multiple beans are eligible for injection to the injection point JSR-299 5.2.1`

Please, Can anyone explain clearly i stucked here.If i continue this way in future it will make any problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to inject an instance of `AInter` bean, but CDI container does not know which implementation to inject. You should use annotation [qualifier](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#qualifiers) to give him a hint, or use alternatives etc.